# Selenium check selected dropdown option value using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have problem in getting the option value selected in dropdown with dynamic name and id. here's the html. Note: I will get the SELECTED OPTION VALUE from the dropdown. Not selecting a value on it.

I used many xpath contains but it doesn't works. the "[1]" changes everytime the page reloads.

Do you have any idea what is the correct xpath contains to use on this. BTW, I'm using web driver 2.32

```
<select name="this.is.dynamic.which.change.every.page.loads[1].select" id="this.is.dynamic.which.change.every.page.loads[1].select"
    <option value> - Select </option>
    <option value="1"> Option1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option3</option>
    <option value="4"> Option4</option>
    <option value="5"> Option5</option>
    <option value="6"> Option6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, I will get the selected dropdown value. I will NOT choose a specific option value in here. The select element also is inside a table

Answer (score 0):

You can still use XPath Contains to match the `Select` then `Option` to Explicitly match your preferred option.

It will be Something like

```
//Select[contains(@name,'any frequent prefix')]/option[.='option']
```

or

```
//Select/option[.='option']
```

Hi Use the Select class in WebDriver API

```
String path = "/Select[contains(@name,'any frequet prefix')]"

Select options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)));
options.getAllSelectedOptions();

System.out.println(options.getAllSelectedOptions());
```

Can findElement by Tag if it's the Only Select/Dropdown on Page

Comment: Hi, I will get the selected dropdown value. I will NOT choose a specific option value in here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky but my way to do that is :

```
//get the value 
String name = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector(select)).getAttribute("name");
int flag = 0;
//loop for getting your dynamic number
for(int i=1; flag!=0; i++){
  if (name.charAt(i).isNumeric()){
    String num = name.charAt(i);
    flag = 1;
  }// end if
}//end for
// now get the value for the selected one
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector(select option:nth-child(num)));
```

It will probably not work (if you copy/past) because i can't test and i'm at work. But you got an idea to get what you want. Tell me what's up.